# How to refactor usages of static tracers with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, refactoring

I just discovered that one of our packages contains 30+ classes that all do

```
private final static Tracer tracer = new Tracer(OwningClass.class, "SOME_TRACE_MASK");
```

Thing is: that information about OwningClass isn't really relevant; but the fact that half of those classes use the same, slightly or completely different trace masks is really annoying.

I think a pragmatic solution would be to have a dedicated:

```
class TraceHolder {
  final static Tracer tracer = new Tracer(TraceHolder.class, "UNIFIED_MASK");
}
```

and then remove all existing tracer objects and use that shared one instead.

But as said: 30+ classes to update.

Is there a nice way to make such kind of changes automatically using eclipse refactoring capabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing that I know of.
30 classes is nothing, you can quickly do it by hand.
But it looks like you may easily do it with search/replace with or without regular expressions.